# here i want the first row complete values

Tags: php, mysql

```
ITEM         CURRENT TOKENS      STATUS               DATE/TIME
mypro        0.10/0.10          ongoing               19/05/2015 17:42:03
mypro        0.20/0.10          ongoing               19/05/2015 17:40:57
myproduct3   0.10/0.10          ongoing               19/05/2015 15:53:1
```

Here I want the first row complete values which is stored recently of same product rather than second product, when I was using `group by` cluase I was getting second row values in mysql database.

Comment: You can also use LIMIT clause

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dates adhere to a specific format in SQL. This is not it.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL knows nothing of first/second row unless you specify it and I'm assuming you want the one the latest `DATE/TIME`.

For simple queries this is easily achieved using an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT`:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table
ORDER BY date_time_col DESC /* Latest rows first */
   LIMIT 1; /* Fetch only the first row */
```

For grouped queries this is more difficult, I like the `LEFT JOIN` approach:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table t1 /* Join to rows of same item & later times */
       ON t1.item_col = t.item_col
      AND t1.date_time_col > t.date_time_col 
    WHERE t1.item_col IS NULL; /* Rows that have no later time */
```

This does assume that `item_col` and `date_time_col` have unique combinations however.

Comment: Thank you for reply,i need first as well third row,but with given query we will get only first..... –

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME DESC LIMIT 1
```

try this

Comment: Thank you for reply,i need first as well third row,but  with given query we will get only first.....

Comment: yes,I m sry,i m sry,but i need 1st and 3 rd where among first two rows the latest value i should retreive...hope u understand my question